# Is there a way to prefer node deployment in docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I got three nodes in my swarm, one manager and two workers (worker1 and worker2). I have a couple of services which preferably is running on the first worker node (worker1), however when this node goes down I wish it to start running on the second worker node.

From what I've gathered I could put a constraint like this.

```
  placement:
    constraints:
    - node.hostname==worker1
```

This however forces the service to be run on worker1 and when that node goes down the service will simply go down.

I could also do this

```
  placement:
    constraints:
     - node.role==worker
```

This restricts the service to either one of the worker nodes but doesn't prioritize worker1 as I want to. Is there a way to prioritize the service to a specific node rather than putting a constraint?

Comment: I don't think so. There's [placement preferences](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#placement), but I think that can only spread out over multiple nodes, which is the opposite of what you want.

Comment: I wan to do exactly the same. Just a suggestion with 3 nodes you can promote them to manager, so you have high availability.